# Condición elif no se cumple

Tags: python

en este ejercicio de calcular la potencia con multiplicaciones sucesivas tengo una duda, por qué en la condición el elif no entra? por que pruebo y me da de respuesta a C, como esta definida antes del for

```
z= 1
C=0
exponente= 0

A = int(input("Ingrese un numero entero como base: "))
B = int(input("Ingrese otro numero entero como exponente: "))

if (B < 0):
    B*= -1
    exponente-=1
else:
    exponente+=1

for i in range (B):

    if (exponente > 0):
        C = A * z     
        z = C

    elif (exponente < 0):
        C = (1/(A*z))  
        z = C

    else:
        C = 1

print ("El resultado es: ", C)
```

Comment: sería bueno indicar ejemplos de salida que sí funcionen y ejemplos que no

Comment: Si pongo A=2 exponente positivo B=3 da bien C = 8 funciona, el problema pasa cuando quiero calcularlo con un exponente negativo o que el exponente sea 0, siempre da de resultado C =0

Comment: ¿cómo vas a hacer un `range()` de un número negativo o 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola el problema es que la funcion `range()` genera un tupla del 0 hasta el numero en este caso si el exponente es 0 nunca entra al while, y hay otro error que es cuando el exponente es negativo ingresé, Base:2 y Exponente:-3 y me da 0.5, lo que propongo es que no ocupes un for si no vas a ocupar la variable "i" para eso ocupa un while

```
z= 1
C=0
exponente= 0

A = int(input("Ingrese un numero entero como base: "))
B = int(input("Ingrese otro numero entero como exponente: "))

if (B < 0):
    B*= -1
    exponente-=1
else:
    exponente+=1

for i in range (B):

    if (exponente > 0):
        C = A * z     
        z = C

    elif (exponente < 0):
        C = (1/(A*z))  
        z = C

    else:
        C = 1

print ("El resultado es: ", C)
```

**Codigo propuesto**

```
z= 1
C=0
exponente= 0
i = 0

A = int(input("Ingrese un numero entero como base: "))
B = int(input("Ingrese otro numero entero como exponente: "))

if B == 0:
  C = 1
else:
  if (B < 0):
      B*= -1
      exponente-=1
  else:
      exponente+=1

  while(i < B):
      C = A * z     
      z = C
      i+=1
  if exponente < 0:
    C = 1/C

print ("El resultado es: ", C)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

No cambié mucho tu codigo. El problema estaba en esta porción, que no hace lo que tu pensaste.

```
elif (exponente < 0):
        C = (1/(A*z))  
        z = C
```

Además, cuando el exponente es cero, el `for i in range(0)` no se ejecuta ninguna vez, por tanto el valor inicial de C debe ser 1, para casos como este. Introducí tu codigo en una función recursiva, si no sabes que es aprovecha y estudialo, es una herramienta muy poderosa.
Aqui te va:

```py
def potencia(A, B):
    z = 1
    C = 1
    if (B < 0):
        return 1 / potencia(A, -1 * B)
    for i in range(B):
        C = A * z
        z = C
    return C

A = int(input("Ingrese un numero entero como base: "))
B = int(input("Ingrese otro numero entero como exponente: "))

print("El resultado es: ", potencia(A, B))
```

Espero que te ayude. Si no endiendes algo, coméntalo por favor y recuerda decir si te sirvió.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! me funcionó